# Output changes in every run reading from file

Tags: c

I'm writing a small application for college that parses some wikipedia pages and outputs information about the people in the pages.

I wrote it in Java and am trying to re-write it in C. I'm getting a weird bug, sometimes the program's output is correct and sometimes it is wrong, without changing the input.

[Here is a sample input that triggers the error](http://pastebin.com/W5hhMiGx) with the name "105.html"

This is the output I get sometimes:

> 105 Linus Pauling Estadunidense 28 de fevereiro de 1901 Portland, Oregon 19 de agosto de 1994 Big Sur, Califórnia  93

This is the output I get other times:

> 105 Linus Pauling Estadunidense 28 de f@evereir@o�y� dC�L��e ���y�19I�L��01 Portland, Oregon 19 de agosto de 1994 Big Sur, Califórnia  93

I notice that if I set a breakpoint in XCode, I usually get the RIGHT result...

I'm new to C so I actually have no clue how to start debugging this.

Here is the code if anyone is interested in actually reading it. The code is in a mixture of Portuguese and English but I added English comments so it should be easy to follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pessoa{
    int id;
    char *nome; //name
    char *nacionalidade; // nationality
    char *nascimento; // date of birth
    char *local_nascimento; // place of birth
    char *morte; // date of death
    char *local_morte; // place of death
    int idade; // age
};


struct pessoa *inicializar(int n) {
    struct pessoa *pessoas = malloc(sizeof(pessoas) * n);
    return pessoas;
}

void imprimir_pessoa(struct pessoa *p) {
    printf("%i %s %s %s %s %s %s  %i\n", p->id, p->nome, p->nacionalidade,
           p->nascimento, p->local_nascimento, p->morte,
           p->local_morte, p->idade);
}

void imprimir_pessoa_asterisco(struct pessoa *p) {
    printf("%i ## %s ## %s ## %s ## %s ## %s ## %s ## %i\n", p->id, p->nome, p->nacionalidade,
           p->nascimento, p->local_nascimento, p->morte,
           p->local_morte, p->idade);
}

size_t index_of(char *string, char *to_find) {
    return strstr(string, to_find) - string;
}

char *remove_tags(char *string) {
    // inicializa para o mesmo tamanho da string de entrada para garantir que ira caber
    char * resp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string) + 1);

    // jumps over the html tags and finds the aproppriate information
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {

        while (i < strlen(string) && string[i] == '<') {
            for (i++; string[i] != '>'; i++);
            i++;

            while(i < strlen(string) && string[i] == '&'){
                for (i++; string[i] != ';'; i++);
                i++;
            }
        }

        while(i < strlen(string) && string[i] == '&'){
            for (i++; string[i] != ';'; i++);
            i++;
            resp[strlen(resp)] = ' ';
        }


        if (i < strlen(string)) {
            resp[strlen(resp)] = string[i];
        }
    }

    while(strlen(string) > 0 && resp[0] == ' '){ // jumps over white spaces on the begining
        resp += 1;
    }
    resp[strlen(resp)] = 0;

    return resp;
}

char* extrair_nome(char *string) { // extract the person's name
    size_t index = index_of(string, "<title>") + strlen("<title>");
    size_t index_fim = index_of(string, " Wiki") - 4;
    char *nome = malloc(sizeof(char) * (index_fim - index));
    memcpy(nome, (string+index), index_fim - index);
    return nome;
}

char* substring(char * string, char *c) {
    return string + strcspn(string, c);
}

void remove_new_line(char *string) {
    char *pos;
    if ((pos=strchr(string, '\n')) != NULL)
        *pos = '\0';
}

void ler_pessoa(char *nome_arquivo, struct pessoa *p) { // parse the file to fill the pessoa struct
    size_t length = strlen(nome_arquivo);
    p->id = (nome_arquivo[length - 8] - 48) * 100;
    p->id = (p->id + (nome_arquivo[length - 7] - 48) * 10);
    p->id = p->id + (nome_arquivo[length - 6] - 48);

    int tamanho_linha = 2000;
    char *linha = malloc(sizeof(char) * tamanho_linha);
    FILE *fp = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Falha ao abrir arquivo %s\n", nome_arquivo);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp) != NULL) {
        if (strstr(linha, "<title>")) { // extracts name
            p->nome = extrair_nome(linha);
            remove_new_line(p->nome);
            break;
        }
    }

    while (fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp) != NULL) {
        if (strstr(linha, "Nacionalidade")) { // extracts nationality
            fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp);
            p->nacionalidade = remove_tags(linha);
            remove_new_line(p->nacionalidade);
            break;
        }
    }

    while (fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp) != NULL) {
        if (strstr(linha, "Nascimento")) { // extracts date of births
            fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp);
            p->nascimento = remove_tags(linha); // <-- this one is not working all the time??
            remove_new_line(p->nascimento);
            break;
        }
    }

    //se vivo
    if (strstr(p->nascimento, ")") != NULL) { // if the person is alive the date of birth date is of the type: date(age)
        char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(p->nascimento)); // so we extract the age
        strcpy(tmp, p->nascimento);
        tmp = tmp + strcspn(tmp, "(") + 1;
        tmp[index_of(tmp, " ")] = 0;
        p->idade = atoi(tmp);
        p->morte = "vivo"; // not dead
        p->local_morte = "vivo"; // not dead
    } else {
        p->morte = ""; // we set this later
        p->local_morte = "";
    }

    while (fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp) != NULL) {
        if (strstr(linha, "Local")) { // extracts place of death
            fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp);
            p->local_nascimento = remove_tags(linha);
            remove_new_line(p->local_nascimento);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (strlen(p->morte) == 0) { // we set this now if the person is not alive (hence size 0)
        while (fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp) != NULL) {
            if (strstr(linha, "Morte")) { // extract death day
                fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp);
                p->morte = remove_tags(linha);
                remove_new_line(p->morte);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (strstr(p->morte, "(") != NULL) {
            char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(p->morte));
            strcpy(tmp, p->morte); // extract age when the person died, like above
            tmp = tmp + strcspn(tmp, "(") + 1;
            tmp[index_of(tmp, " ")] = 0;
            p->idade = atoi(tmp);
            p->morte[index_of(p->morte, "(")] = 0;
        }

        while (fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp) != NULL) {
            if (strstr(linha, "Local")) { // get the place of death
                fgets(linha, tamanho_linha, fp);
                p->local_morte = remove_tags(linha);
                remove_new_line(p->local_morte);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct pessoa p;
    ler_pessoa("/tmp/105.html", &p);
    imprimir_pessoa(&p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wall of code, no detail information. See [ask], post a **[MCVE]**. We are no debugging service.

Comment: I have no idea what part is giving me the error, that's why I posted the whole program. I added English comments everywhere to help anyone read it. The code is there in case anyone actually wants to read it. I'm not asking you to read it, I'm asking what would cause the output to change in different runs when reading from the file.

Comment: What could? Some undefined behaviour, perhaps caused by execeeding array bounds, or using or uninitialised variables. Please turn up your compiler warnings to max.

Comment: @WeatherVane I get no warnings with -Wall

Comment: You have not allowed room for a `nul` string terminator in your `malloc`, `char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(p->morte));` followed by `strcpy`.

Comment: Your `index_of` function does not account for the possibility that the target string is not found.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok, I added an extra space on all the malloc calls for string but the error persists

Comment: In one, you used `memcpy`. That does not copy the terminator.

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha Are you aware about [how many problems has your program](http://pastebin.com/raw/WLD0rsrd)?

Comment: @Michi no I was not aware of that. How can I see that?

Comment: If you are using `GCC` then:   1) `gcc-6 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wold-style-definition -O0 -g -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -std=c11 program.c -o program`  and then step 2)  `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full ./program`

Comment: @Michi thanks, I'll start debugging with that.

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha When you start debugging you should know that Errors should be fixed starting with line 1 to line N..

Comment: `resp[strlen(resp)] = ' ';` and `resp[strlen(resp)] = string[i];` are bad as `resp` is not certainly null character terminated.

Comment: @Augusto Dias Noronha  Curious, what did your think `resp[strlen(resp)] = 0;` does?

Comment: @chux set the character after the last one to \0?

Comment: @chux that was it duuude thank you very much... I don't know why I thought that. It's working now!

Comment: The post had the quality of at least compiling clean - unfortunately that is  rare.

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha: `-Wall` does not mean all warnings. See the gcc man-page or google for "gcc documentation"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resp[strlen(resp)] = ' ';` and `resp[strlen(resp)] = string[i];` are bad as `resp[]` is not certainly null character terminated.

Code needs a new approach to determine which element of `resp[]` to assign.

---

`resp[strlen(resp)] = 0;` is questionable too.

`strlen(resp)` returns the length of the string, not counting the null terminator.  For `strlen()` to work well, `resp` must be null terminated *first*, else it is not referencing a *string*.  The null character is in the index that equals the length, so  `resp[strlen(resp)] = 0;` is a no-op function, other than killing some CPU cycles.

---

Code has other problems.
Example: Insufficient space.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580359/output-changes-in-every-run-reading-from-file?noredirect=1#comment66470885_39580359);

```
// bad code
char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(p->nascimento)); // so we extract the age
strcpy(tmp, p->nascimento);
```

Sample string allocator/duplicator  (Note: `strdup()` often exists on many platforms)

```
char *strdupe(const char *s) {
  size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
  dupe = malloc(size);
  if (dupe) {
    memcpy(dupe, s, size);
  }
  return dupe;
}
```